# Increment property value with keyboard

Tags: interface

Basic question - how do you increment value with keyboard (when you're in a field in one of the windows, e.g., "X" and "Y" coordinates? I assume up or down key but doesn't seem to work

Thanks!

Comment: You can't. It's just not a concept of blender to use a keyboard shortcut for that. The blender method is left click and drag to the left/right on the value field. You could have found that out by reading the docs or watching one of the many beginner tutorials on youtube. Thats why I downvoted this question. It's better to use the blender IRC chat for this type of short question. Don't let my downvote discourage you from asking more involved questions here, it's not personal.

Comment: @bertmoog Thanks for telling me! Downvote retracted.

Comment: thanks bertmoog. and a bit harsh TeeTrinker ... i did spend hours on beginner training and couldn't track it down

Comment: that said, thanks for flagging the other forum ... didn't know there was one for more basic questions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @TeeTrinker said, you can left-click and drag the mouse to change the value in the field.  Of course, this will change the value by increments of 0.01.  If you want the value to change by increments of 1.0, you can hold down <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> while dragging:

[image]

An alternate way, purely by keyboard is to simply add 1.0 to the value in the field by typing <kbd>+</kbd> <kbd>1</kbd> and pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>:

[image]

There may be other ways through scripts but I'm unsure.